# Laravel mix minimize copied files

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-mix, minimize

I have question.

Is it possible to minimize copied files with function `mix.copy()`?

I can't use `mix.js()` becouse when I run npm generator my js scripts didn't works. Also I want to minimize my css files, becouse I don't use scss.

Comment: Use `mix.scripts` to merge/minimise js files ,  `mix.copy` to copy compiled files and `mix.styles` to merge/minimise css files

Comment: Cerlin it's works thank you, please wrtie answer I'll honor you.